# Question about $\langle b\rangle$ in a Hausdorff Topological Group

Tags: topological-groups

Let $G$ be a topological Hausdorff group, if $b\in G$, does there exist an open neighborhood of $b$ such that $U\cap \langle b\rangle$ is finite.

I know this is a really odd question, but I would really appreciate to know whether this is true or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. For example, let $G$ be the unit circle in the complex plane, that is, the points $e^{it}$, where $t$ ranges over the reals, under the usual multiplication. Let $b=e^{it_0}$, where $t_0$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$. It can be shown that the group generated by $b$ is dense in the unit circle.

You may be more familiar with the result in the following form. Suppose that $\tau$ is irrational. Then the set of fractional parts of $n\tau$, as $n$ ranges over the natural numbers, is dense in the unit interval.

Comment: could I ask something else?, does the property hold if $G$ is torsion-free?

Comment: I certainly cannot think of an off-hand counterexample, and can sort of see how one might construct a proof. I think this would be an excellent separate question.

Comment: A torsion-free example is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the group of $p$-adic integers.

Comment: @PinkElephants, why?

Comment: Suppose $b\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ is non-zero. The subgroup generated by $b$ contains the distinct elements $b+p^nb$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, and every neighborhood of $b$ contains $b+p^nb$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Additionally, if $b\not\in p\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $\langle b\rangle$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.